# error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm trying to build am opensource game but keep getting this error when trying to build. I have been searching for the last half hour with nothing working here's the code the errors pointing to

```
void duel::restore_assumes() {
    for(auto pcard : assumes)
        pcard->assume_type = 0;
    assumes.clear();
}
```

and the error is

> Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before
>   ':'   c:\users\user\desktop\project source\ocgcore\duel.cpp   108 1   ocgcore
>   (Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: I don't know how good VS2010 is with C++11

Comment: im using vs2012 but changed compiler to vs2010 because it wouldnt make the lib file when compiled with 2012 compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS VC++ 2010 does not support the range based for statement that was introduced in the C++ 2011. However it has its own language extension: `for each`.

Try to change this code

```
void duel::restore_assumes() {
    for(auto pcard : assumes)
        pcard->assume_type = 0;
    assumes.clear();
}
```

to

```
void duel::restore_assumes() {
    for each (auto pcard in assumes)
        pcard->assume_type = 0;
    assumes.clear();
}
```

Otherwise you can use an ordinary loop with iterators of object assumes or some standard algorithm as for example `std::for_each`

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly the program was made with vs2010 so when vs2012 opened it it must have changed it during the conversion

Answer (score 3):

As shown in this table : [C++11 Compiler Support](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport)

Range-based for Loops aren't available with MSVC2010, but with MSVC2012 (which is version 11).
So if you use the 2010 compiler, this code won't compile.

The error message makes it pretty obvious: the compiler is not expecting a `:` in the for statement.

Comment: but when i use the 2012 compiler no lib file is generated

Comment: Well this is another problem then, which may not be in the scope of this question. Create another topic, post code, configuration and observed behaviors.